# Representability of sheaf of Ext^1 of a Néron model by $\mathbb{G}_m$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, neron-models, representable-functors, group-schemes

Let's work over a trait $S=\mathrm{Spec}R$, where $R$ is a dvr with fraction field $K$, residue field $k$. Given an abelian variety $A_K$ with semi-stable reduction, let $A$ over $S$ be its Néron model and $A^{\circ}$ the neutral component. We know the sheaf $\mathscr{E}xt^1(A^{\circ},\mathbb{G}_m)$ is represented by the Néron model of the dual of $A_K$ over the category of smooth scheme over $S$, see (Mazur and Messing's LNM Universal extensions and one dimensional crystalline cohomology, chapter I section 5)

My question is: Is the sheaf $\mathscr{E}xt^1(A^{\circ},\mathbb{G}_m)$ also representable over the category of schemes over $S$?

Also we know the Poincaré biextension $W_K$ of $A_K$ and $A_K^'$ by $\mathbb{G}_m$ extends to a biextension $W$ of certain open subgroups of $A$ and $A'$ (i.e. the subgroups making the component pairing vanish),
my second question is if $W$ is represented by a scheme over $S$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First question: no. Assume, to fix ideas, that $R$ is complete with uniformizer $\pi$, $k$ is algebraically closed, and $A$ is an elliptic curve with multiplicative reduction. Denote by $\mathscr{E}$ the Ext sheaf in question. Then the restriction of $A^\circ$ to $S_n:=\mathrm{Spec\,}(R/(\pi^{n+1}))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_{m}$, so $\mathscr{E}(S_n)$ is zero for all $n$. If $\mathscr{E}$ were a scheme, this would imply $\mathscr{E}(R)=0$ (the functor of points of a scheme "commutes with completion" for *local* rings), a contradiction.

Second question: yes, because $W$ is a $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor over the product, and torsors under affine group schemes are schemes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please tell me the reference for 1. "the functor of points of a scheme "commutes with completion" for local rings"; 2. "torsors under affine group schemes are schemes"

Comment: @ Laurent Moret-Bailly: Is $A^{'\circ}$ like an "open" subsheaf of $\mathscr{E}xt^1(A,\mathbb{G}_m)$ over the category of schemes over S? How to understand the relation between the two?

Comment: Concerning completions: I don't know a reference but this is an exercise. First observe that for an *affine* scheme, the functor of points commutes with arbitrary inverse limits of rings (this is trivial).  

For an arbitrary scheme $X$, a filtered inverse system of local rings $R_i$ (with local transition maps) and compatible elements $f_i$ of $X(R_i)$, observe that all closed points of the spectra must map to the same point $x$ of $X$, hence all $f_i$'s must factor through any affine neighborhood of $x$, so we are reduced to the affine case.

Comment: Concerning representability of torsors: this is just flat descent of affine morphisms (SGA1, VIII, th. 2.1). For the special case of torsors, I am sure this is stated in Demazure-Gabriel. 
