# What does the Néron model of the dual abelian variety parametrize?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, neron-models

Let $K$ be a field which is complete with respect to a discrete valuation $v$ with ring of integers $R$ and residue field $k$. Let $A$ an abelian variety over $K$ and let $A^t$ be the dual abelian variety. Now we can take the Néron model $X$ of $A$ and also the Néron model $X^t$ of $A^t$. Is there any relation between $X^t(R)$ and line bundles on $X$?

Here are some immature thoughts:

Since $K$-points of $X^t$ are $K$-points of $A^t$, we have that $X^t(K)$ is in one-to-one correspondence with line bundles of degree zero on $X_K=A$. Now it is clear that the exact same statement cannot be true for the special fiber but there seems to be still some relation.
For instance let $A$ be an elliptic curve with bad reduction and assume for simplicity that $k$ is algebraically closed. Then the identity component of $(X^t)_k$ is $(k^*,*)$ if $A$ has multiplicative reduction and $(k,+)$ if $A$ has additive reduction (since A=A^t). This is exactly the degree zero part of the Picard group of the nodal curve in the first case and the cuspidal curve in the second case.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a special case that's already quite interesting. If $A$ is the Jacobian of a smooth projective curve $C/K$ with minimal regular model $\mathcal{C}/R$, then $A = A^t$ and the identity component of $X_k$ is isomorphic to $\text{Pic}^0_{C_k/k}$, when the gcd of the multiplicities of $C_k$ is one; this is a theorem of Raynaud and explains your elliptic curve example.

Comment: Of course $X^t(R) = A^t(K)$ just corresponds to degree zero line bundles on $A$, but there is a more subtle relationship too. The universal line bundle on $A \times A^t$ (Poincare bundle) gives rise to a so-called biextension of $A\times A^t$. Grothendieck showed that it extends to a biextension on $X^{0}\times (X^t)^{0}$. For (rather intricate) details, SGA7, Expose IX.

Comment: Also this question seems very related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114337/representability-of-sheaf-of-ext1-of-a-néron-model-by-mathbbg-m?rq=1

Comment: I doubt that there is a good answer to your question in general.  If we knew an elementary functorial property of the N'eron model, then it would be much easier to construct (e.g., by checking Artin's algebraization axioms).  The fact that the current constructions of the N'eron model are not so easy (e.g., using the auxiliary invariant differential forms) suggests that there is no good answer.  On the other hand, if you find a good answer, you can use that to try to give a simple construction of N'eron models!

Comment: I read more about this in a survey article of Cedric PEPIN: https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~cpepin/neron-picard-final.pdf  There is "almost" a functorial description.  There is a "semi-normal", proper $R$-model $\overline{A}$ of $A_K$, and the N'eron model $A^\dagger$ is the unique "group smoothening" of the relative $\text{Pic}^0$ of $\overline{A}/R$.  As noted by user @Jef, when the groups of connected components of the closed fibers of $A$ and $A^\dagger$ are nontrivial, the Poincar'e bundle almost never extends.  So the group smoothening is nontrivial.

Comment: "semi-normal" --> "semi-factorial"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and thoughts! I will have a look at these references.